# Org-mode: how to convert date format?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'm using Emacs org-mode's agenda feature.

When I put a timestamp on an item in my gtd.org file, with C-c . , it will show up in my agenda for the week.  The date is in this format: <2011-12-25 Sun>

If I use M-x holidays to get a list of holidays, the dates are in this format:
Sunday, December 25, 2011: Christmas

How can I add holidays to my gtd.org file, in a format that shows up in the agenda?

I've looked through the Emacs manual and the org-mode manual, for either a way to change the date formats in 'holidays', or a way to convert a date into org-mode's format.

Answer (score 1):

You can add them to the calendar by adding the following SEXP to your org file:
    %%(org-calendar-holidays)

See: [Calendar/Diary Integration](http://orgmode.org/manual/Weekly_002fdaily-agenda.html)

The specifc entry in your org file could be as follows (This works just like this):

```
* Holidays
:PROPERTIES:
:CATEGORY: Holiday
:END:
%%(org-calendar-holidays)
```

If you want a different category or different name for the headline, you can do so. But as a generic entry it will provide the information you want. (It matches what my org-file has)

Comment: I haven't been able to get this to work.  I'm new to Emacs, and once again, I'm puzzled.

Comment: I haven't been able to get this to work.  I'm new to Emacs, and once again, I'm puzzled.  I did add "#+%%(org-calendar-holiday)" to the org file I'm using, without effect.  I've read about the diary, but I don't seem to have a diary file defined and I'm getting nowhere trying to fix this.  I'm not really trying to use a diary file; I'm trying to convert dates from one format to another.

Comment: See my edit, I'll put in a specific example of what the lines would look like.

Comment: Ah, much better!  This works, but something is askew in the date ranges. Here is part of my agenda for the rest of the week -- the diary file contains all holidays for 2011 and 2012:

Thursday   24 November 2011
  Holiday:    Thanksgiving
  Diary:      Thanksgiving
  Diary:      November 24, 2011: Thanksgiving
  Diary:      February 2, 2012: Groundhog Day
  Diary:      June 14, 2012: Flag Day
Friday     25 November 2011
  Diary:       5:11...... December 21, 2012: Winter Solstice (CST)
  Diary:      April 6, 2012: Good Fri
  Diary:      July 20, 2012: Ramadan Begins

Comment: Um... so much for my nicely-formatted comment.  Not sure where I should add a detailed response, as I tried just above.

Comment: @user11583 maybe edit your original post and add the new information?

Comment: Latest versions of org-mode (I'm at Org-mode version 8.2.7c) have changed the function: should be `%%(org-calendar-holiday)'